# Resizing content in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I am creating a scrollview programmatically and adding subviews to it programmatically. The subviews are created programmatically as well.

I am just wondering how to rotate / resize the subview so that it remains visible in landscape mode.

I have set the scrollview to `autorotateSubviews:YES` and in my subview i have set the mask to be `flexiblewidth|flexibleheight` is this correct?

I am used to doing this in IB with the springs and struts section of the inspector.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll view is probably contained in a view witha  corresponding controller that receives willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: notifications. Use these opportunities to resize the subviews of the scrollview.